# Bounded variation implies Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: derivatives, lebesgue-integral

Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded variation.

Let $f_a(x) = f(a)+ \int_a^x f' dm$ be the indefinite integral of $f$.

Let $g= f - f_a$.

Show $g$ is singular i.e $g'=0$ a.e.

Attempt:

Since $f \in BV[a,b]$, $f' $ exists a.e $f'$ is integrable.

So we can use just simply use the definition of differentiation and Lebesgue differentiation theorem to show that $f_s'(x)= f'(x)-f'(x)$.

But the problem is that to use the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, we need to have $f \in L^1[a,b]$.

I'm not sure if that is true.

So does $f\in BV[a,b]$ imply $f \in L^1[a,b]$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f = v-(v-f)$ where $v(x)$ is the variation of $f$ from $a$ to $x$.  From this decomposition we see that $f$ is the difference of two increasing functions, $v$ and $v-f$. Monotone functions are measurable so $f$ is measurable, and any monotone functions are bounded on $[a,b]$ by their endpoint values, so in fact $f$ is bounded and hence integrable.

Answer (score 0):

It actually implies that Riemann integrable since the set of points at which f is discontinuous is countable hence measure zero.

Look at Folland's real anlysis 3.27 Theorem.